# SImple C program with array is not printing proper output

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote this incredibly stupid code

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int new[10], i;
    for(i=1; i<=10; ++i){
            new[i] = 0;
            }

for(i=1;i<=10; ++i)
            {
                    printf("%d", new[i]);
            }
 }
```

I compiled this using GCC on Xubuntu and then did the ./a.out. The cursor is just blinking resulting in no output. The same is the case when tried to debug with gdb. It runs and then stays with the blinking cursor.

Any help?

Comment: Don't use `new` for variable names - it's a keyword.

Comment: `new` is not a keyword in C.

Comment: Could've sworn this question was titled C++ a second ago...

Comment: I don't see any edits.

Comment: `new` is not a keyword in c, but in this era it is probably better to avoid using it as a identifier in new (heh!) code, simply because so many c programmers also write c++ and so much c code gets included into c++ projects.

Comment: @CarlNorum if the asker himself edits the question within a few minutes of posting no edit history shows.

Comment: @nightcracker I just learned C and debugging. I have to learn C++.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `new` is a keyword in C++ and not in C, regardless programming language, `new` definitely shouldn't be used as variable name. It pricks somebody eyes, because it looks like syntax error. JavaScript was throwing error while using `class` as variable, and that was very good idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C arrays are 0 indexed - your program writes outside the boundaries of the `new` array, so it causes undefined behaviour.  In this case, you probably are overwriting the `i` variable, so you end up with an infinite loop.  You need to change your loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    new[i] = 0;
}
```

and:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Comment: Hi! It worked! Could you tell me why I didn't encounter the error in MinGW?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.  Anything could happen, including the possibility of correct-looking behaviour.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I went paranoid when it didn't print anything.

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu The c compiler never promises to detect programer intent. You are assumed to know what you are doing and to say what you mean; if you ask for something strange (or even stupid) the compiler will generally give it to you.

Comment: @dmckee I assume it is very generous :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a new line character to see the output , or flush the stdout otherwise sometimes it doesn't print, or it will be combined with the next line... try:

```
printf("%d\n", new[i]);
```

also, set your for loop from 0 to 9

Answer (score 1):

`int new[10]` - Here `new` array can store 10 elements of type integer. You can access these elements from 0th to 9th index of array. Accessing beyond 9th index is undefined behavior.